# Visual Studio/.NET Service Reference HTTP Version

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, service-reference

I am adding a "service reference" to my project and we are experiencing an issue we believe may be due to a variance in the HTTP version (1.0 vs. 1.1).  Does anyone know which version is used by default or where I can find out during my request which version is used?

Comment: Why do you believe it is to do with the HTTP version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you believe it is to do with the HTTP version? Anyway, Service Refernces are generated using svcutil.exe which [uses HTTP 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738574%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).